# Timeout when connecting to Vagrant VM via hostname with port forwarding

Tags: networking, vagrant

I am trying to get a Vagrant VM setup that has been distributed to me (so I did not configure it myself). I have installed the VM using `vagrant up`successfully, but when I try to use a browser to hit the hostname I get a timeout. I have set the hostname in my hosts file too.

Config in Vagrantfile:

```
# Networking
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.28"
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 80, auto_correct: true
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 443, auto_correct: true
config.vm.hostname = "mysite.local"
```

Line in my hosts file:

```
192.168.33.28   mysite.local secure.mysite.local
```

When I try to browse to http://mysite.local I get a timeout.

I have tried to change the Vagrantfile config to:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
```

and then running `vagrant reload`. After this I still get a timeout for `http://mysite.local:8080` but I get a successful response for `http://localhost:8080`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First, you can't bind to ports below 1024 (on host) without root/sudo (and you shouldn't run Vagrant as root). I would assume you get some error/warning message from that, but maybe the `auto_correct` just binds to some non-privileged port.

And as you already specify a `private_network` IP address for the machine, you don't even need any port forwarding. Direct connection should work.

For the timeout I can think of at least the following reasons:

- A firewall on the guest or host
- HTTP proxy configuration which doesn't exclude "mysite.local" or "192.168.33.28"
- The web server redirecting http://mysite.local URLs to a non-reachable domain
- 192.168.33.28 being used by another VM or overlapping other network on the host